# Unable to assign data to a variable

Tags: android, json, kotlin, variables, kotlin-coroutines

I have a problems with assigning data to a variable `eventsString`.
I load data from network using retrofit at coroutine, then I put loaded data to `eventsString`, BUT `eventsString` still has `12`. What is wrong?

```
class OverviewViewModel: ViewModel() {
    
    var eventsString: String = "12"
    init {

        getEventsFromNet()
        println(eventsString) //here i get in comsole "12"
    }

     fun getEventsFromNet(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                eventsString = EventApi.retro.getEvents()
               
                println(eventsString) //here i see in console loaded json, but at UI i still have "12"

            }
            catch (e: Exception){eventsString= "Failure: ${e.message}"}
        }
    }
 
}
```

my retrofitService

```
private const val BASE_URL = "https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/"

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

interface EventApiService{
    @GET("launches") 
    suspend fun getEvents():String
}

object EventApi{
    val retro :EventApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(EventApiService::class.java)
    }

}
```

At UI I show it with databinding:

```
android:text="@{viewModel.eventsString}"
```

LiveData version - same problems

```
class OverviewViewModel: ViewModel() {
//class OverviewViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    var _events = MutableLiveData<String>()
//    val events : LiveData<String>
//    get() = _events


    var eventsString: String = "12"
    init {

        getEventsFromNet()
        println(eventsString)
    }

     fun getEventsFromNet(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                _events = EventApi.retro.getEvents()
                println("try")
                println(eventsString)

            }
            catch (e: Exception){eventsString= "Failure: ${e.message}"}
        }
    }

}
```

retrofitservice

```
private const val BASE_URL = "https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/"//"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

interface EventApiService{
    @GET("launches") //"posts"
    suspend fun getEvents():MutableLiveData<String>
}

object EventApi{
    val retro :EventApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(EventApiService::class.java)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the ui code as well, to see how/when are accessing this var?

Comment: API call is asynchronous you have to wait for its response . Use `LiveData` to observe the response . You observe the LiveData and the update the UI .

Comment: At UI i show it with databinding:

android:text="@{viewModel.eventsString}"     Also i already trying with liveData - have same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `LiveData.value = ...` instead.

- ViewModel

```kotlin
class OverviewViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val _events = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val events get() = _events as LiveData<String>()

    init {
        getEventsFromNet()
    }

     fun getEventsFromNet(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _events.value = try { EventApi.retro.getEvents() }
                            catch (e: Exception) { "Failure: ${e.message}" }
    }
}
```

- Fragment/Activity

```kotlin
// Fragment
// Specify the fragment view as the lifecycle owner of the binding.
// This is used so that the binding can observe LiveData updates
binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

// or Activity
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```

- Layout

```xml
android:text="@{viewModel.events}"
```

Comment: Bro, you are AWESOME)))) 60 peoples watched my question (some of them dislike it), and only you read my code and found errors. Thank you a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for the suspend function to finish getting data and then assign data to the variable. Please check example below.
[enter link description here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Introduction%20to%20Coroutines%20and%20Channels/04_Suspend)

Comment: Chào bạn haha hahah